# Is there a log of all activity I could open in terminal?

Tags: command-line, process, log

I'd like to have a terminal opened and study the processes and everything happening in a regular use of Ubuntu. What commands and files can I use to see the logs in real-time?

Thanks.

Comment: To see the current activity down to individual syscalls , you could [use csysdig](https://sysdig.com/blog/announcing-csysdig-strace-htop-lua-container-support/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For viewing logs in real-time, use `tail -f -n [number of lines] [file]`.

- `-f` is for follow, which will pipe the appended log data to stdout
  (e.g. console window) as the data is written to the file
- `-n` is for number of lines to follow

A good place to start would be `/var/log/syslog`. This is the default log file for many system events, services, and applications.

```
sudo tail -f -n 1000 /var/log/syslog
```

Your target service or application may use a different log file. Some services and applications have multiple log files. The Apache Web server, for example, has separate logs for access, errors, and SSL events. Also, some log files are configured to roll off into an archive file (usually in the same directory) after the original file reaches a certain size, e.g. 1 KB. Check the service or application's documentation (or search) for specific log file locations.

Also, you may find it helpful to open several console windows, and monitor multiple logs at once while you perform a test.

For example, if you were tracing events in a Web application that ran on Apache and used a MySQL database, you may want to open the following two commands in their own console windows. In fact, you may wish to trace these application logs along with the system log from above.

```
sudo tail -f -n 1000 /var/log/apache2/error_log
sudo tail -f -n 1000 /var/log/mysqld.log
```

As always, check the `tail` `man` pages for a full list of options:

`man tail`

Comment: For some logs, `sudo` may or may not be necessary depending on your user's privileges and the access rights on the file. You may need to be `root` or in the `root` group, which has critical security implications, so proceed carefully.

Comment: this is what I was looking for, a kind of default log file for many systems. Many thanks.

Comment: Ubuntu uses the `rsyslog` daemon to log system messages, and `rsyslog` implements a feature called rate limiting. According to http://www.rsyslog.com/tag/rate-limiting/, "this option limits the amount of messages written into logfiles by a process [for] huge amounts of messages in a short period of time." If you ever see `rsyslog` messages in your log file, it could mean that rate limiting has taken effect and kept new messages from being written to the log. You may need to adjust the `rsyslog` configuration to increase rate limits so you can see logged messages for your processes.

Answer (score 10):

Many things you simply cannot spot, because they are handled inside the application or process without *any* communication to "the outer world".

a random (totally incomplete) list of a few of the most important tools you could use however to monitor specific sections of what is going on:

- the `top` command: from `man top`:
  *The  top  program  provides  a dynamic real-time view of a running system.  It can display system summary information as  well  as  a list  of processes or threads currently being managed by the Linux kernel.  The types of system summary  information  shown  and  the types,  order  and size of information displayed for processes are all user configurable and that configuration can be  made  persis‐tent across restarts.*
- `dstat`. From man `dstat`:
  *Dstat allows you to view all of your system resources instantly, you can eg. compare disk usage in combination with interrupts from your IDE controller, or compare the network bandwidth numbers directly with the disk throughput (in the same interval)*
- `wmctrl`; although `wmctrl` does not provide realtime *ongoing* information, when used in a loop in a script, it is fairly easy to retrieve an almost realtime report or log on what happens concerning opened/moved/closed windows.
- The `dbus-monitor` command, of which @Serg should be able to tell you much more. From `man dbus-monitor`:
  *The dbus-monitor command is used to monitor messages going through a D-Bus message bus. See http://www.freedesktop.org/software/dbus/ for more information about the big picture.* (in short: `dbus` is a simple way for applications to talk to one another. **Note** that `dbus-monitor` only works in cases where `dbus` is used, not as a general tool as mentioned by @heemayl (thanks!) )
- The `dconf watch` command (relatively unknown). From `man dconf`:

  ```
     watch
         Watch a key or directory for changes.
  ```

  Try e.g. what happens in the output of `dconf watch /` , while editing system settings.

The bottom line is that there are many, many tools, each and every one of them to spot a specific section of what is happening. A one fits all answer is quite impossible, let alone a single terminal window to show even the beginning of "the whole picture".

Which tool is fit for your purpose depends on what events you specifically want to monitor.

Comment: Jacob, `dbus` works for processes that use `dbus` for their IPC, not a generalization..

Comment: @heemayl I know, but it can give you usefull realtime information in many cases. Will add the remark though.

Comment: Well, the only cases where `dbus` is being used..Nothing more, nothing less..

Comment: @heemayl Thanks! edited  it into to the answer.

Comment: `dstat` is cool, I didn't know about that.

Comment: htop works fine too

Answer (score 6):

Try `history` command, it displays the last `$HISTSIZE` (default 500) executed command in terminal.

`journalctl` command displays log messages, if system uses `systemd`.

`ps -aux` shows running processes, can be used with

```
ps -aux|grep xxxx
```

to select a specific process.

Answer (score 1):

*All activity* is pretty broad.  To add to the existing answers:

- `dmesg` dumps the kernel log to the terminal.  [Man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man1/dmesg.1.html).
- `strace` allows real-time tracing of all system calls from single a given process.  [Man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man1/strace.1.html).  [Ubuntu page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Strace).
- `perf` "strace on steroids."  Perf is a very powerful tool for tracing events at various different granularities across the system, including kernel, individual process and individual CPU.  [Man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/perf.1.html).