# terminal that logs to dbus

Tags: command-line, dbus, zeitgeist, synapse

do you know of a terminal that logs file accesses and such to dbus?

I am asking because I have been using the xterm more than any file explorers but xterm does not send anything to dbus. This has ruined the usability of synapse for me because nothing I am doing gets tracked by zeitgeist.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you are looking for is `dbus-monitor` inside your xterm, see this similar question: [Is there a log of all activity I could open in terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/767481/is-there-a-log-of-all-activity-i-could-open-in-terminal) especially this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/767517/997445